Is this vector field $F(x) = -\frac{mMGx}{\vert x \vert^3}$ conservative?
Is $F(\vec{x}) = -\frac{mMG \vec{x} }{ | \vec{x} |^3 } $ conservative?    ( $\vec{x} =  \langle x, y, z \rangle $ )
In my book, $F(\vec{x})$ is conservative because there exist function $f(x, y, z) = \frac{mMG}{ \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2} }$ s.t. $F(\vec{x}) =  \nabla f(x, y, z)$.
But $G( \vec{x}) = \frac{-y \hat {i} + x \hat{j}  }{x^2 + y^2} $ isn't conservative although there exist function $g(x, y) = -\arctan(\frac{x}{y}) $ s.t. $G(\vec{x}) =  \nabla g(x, y)$  because $ \oint_{C} G(\vec{x}) \cdot d \vec{r} = 0 $ dosen't hold for all closed curve $C$.
This procedure is not same to former. Don't I need to check by evaluating for all close curve for $F(\vec{x}) = -\frac{mMG \vec{x} }{ | \vec{x} |^3 } $?
I'm confused by these two different ways.

There are many posts on MSE discussing those functions. In short: sgn$(y)\arccos(\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$ is a better choice for $g(x,y)$ since that has fewer discontinuities but the same gradient. Nonetheless,  any such $g(x,y)$ will never be continuous on all of $\mathbb R^2\setminus{0},.$ In contrast: in the $\mathbb R^3$-example $F$ and $f$ are singular only in the origin and $\mathbb R^3\setminus{0}$ is simply connected while $\mathbb R^2\setminus{0}$ is not. Look up the Poincare lemma and

maybe this post.

The function $g(x, y)$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus {0}$, so it's not a valid potential.

$G$ has a potential on every local, but does not admit a global potential. The former property is called "closed" and the latter is called "exact", exactness implies closedness, but not otherwise. De Rham cohomology characterizes this phenomenon.

Your question is rather vague, in particular your discussion of the vector field $G(\vec x)$, because you do not specify the domain. For example, $G(\vec x)$ is conservative on the domain $y>0$ for the reasons you gave: it has a potential function on that domain. But one could apply the formula for $G(\vec x)$ on the domain $\mathbb R - {(0,0)}$, and it is not conservative on that domain, also for the reasons you give. This is not a contradiction. So what are you asking?

What I wanted to ask is that why there is no need to check $\oint_{C} f(x,y,z) \cdot d \vec{r} $
